# Sending email from a test

Tags: django

Django 1.9.6

Could you help me understand what is happening here. In settings.py I have organized everything for sending mail.

Namely:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mail.ru'
EMAIL_PORT = 2525
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'ggggggg@mail.ru'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'ggggggg'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'ggggggg@mail.ru'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'ggggggg@mail.ru'
```

Then I have prepared a test:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.mail import send_mail

class GeneralTest(TestCase):

    def test_sending_email(self):
        number_of_successfully_delivered_messages = send_mail("Subject mail", 
                                                              "Message mail", 
                                                              'tttt@mail.ru', 
                                                              ['ggggg@mail.ru'])
        self.assertEqual(number_of_successfully_delivered_messages, 1)
```

The test passes. But email doesn't come to me. When I try it in django shell, emails arrive.

Could you comment on what is going on here and where in documentation can I reed about this situation?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

> If any of your Django views send email using Django’s email functionality, you probably don’t want to send email each time you run a test using that view. For this reason, Django’s test runner automatically redirects all Django-sent email to a dummy outbox. This lets you test every aspect of sending email – from the number of messages sent to the contents of each message – without actually sending the messages.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#topics-testing-email

This is a good thing, as it allows you to do lots of unit tests using emails, without actually sending all these potentially hundreds of emails.